# Install Only Excel 2013 also installs Lync

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2013

I've used the Office Customization Tool to create an Excel Only install.  However, in  addition to Excel, it installs Lync.  These are my settings for feature states in the OCT:

[image]

I've most definitely set Lync to Not Available, but it still installs.

Things I've tried.

I've downloaded updated OCT files (part of the Office 2013 Admin Templates download), imported my existing ExcelOnly.MSP, and then unset and set the Not Available state on Lync just to re-iterate that I don't want it installed. --> Nope, still installs Lync.

I've added an entry in the config.xml file specifically for Lync:

```
<OptionState Id="LyncCoreFiles" State="Absent" Children="force" />
```

But nope, still installs Lync as well as Excel.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: We never figured it out, but decided it wasn't worth the trouble to pursue.  We will allow Lync to install, and just prevent it from starting automatically.  Not very satisfying, I know, but practical in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further down the road now with the Office 2013 deployment.  I'm almost certain that this was actually a bug in the OCT that came with Office 2013 SP1.  I subsequently downloaded OCT again, and noticed that OCT.dll was a higher version.  Since then, there has been no issue with Lync getting installed when it shouldn't, or not installed when it should.

I also had a need to revert to the older OCT for another reason, and noticed Lync didn't install when it should have, further confirming some sort of bug with the earlier OCT version related to Lync installation state.